# Inflating view inside an alert dialog

Tags: android

I need to ask as how should I inflate three buttons in an alert dialog. Basically a list view is available , and when user long presses on the list items , an alert dialog should appear, the dialog should have edit, delete and some other button, the buttons should perform their tasks when pressed, I'd really appreciate it, if someone could tell me as how I should inflate the alert dialog with the buttons.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to invent the wheel twice..
Its called a context menu:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use the AlertDialog.Buider you can add three buttons.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setPositiveButton("Edit", new OnClickListener()
        {
            // Code Here
        })
    .setNeutralButton("Delete", new OnClickListener()
        {
            // Code Here
        })
    .setNegativeButton("Delete", new OnClickListener()
        {
            // Code Here
        })
    .create()
    .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context menu, Like so:

```
final OnCreateContextMenuListener occml = new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        menu.setHeaderTitle(pi.getBrowserIdentifier());
        menu.add(R.id.actionBarMenu_Settings, R.string.one, 1, getString(R.string.one));
        menu.add(R.id.actionBarMenu_Settings, R.string.two, 2, getString(R.two));
        menu.add(R.id.actionBarMenu_Settings, R.string.three, 3, getString(R.string.three));
    };
_listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
_listView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(occml);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am doing it like this, also you can

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Seçenekler");
    builder.setAdapter( /*#your adapter here#*/, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//do something
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The next code capture a view override setView in a custom dialog class extends alertdialog:

```
class example extends Activity{


private void onClick_show_dialog( View v )
{


    LayoutInflater lainf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View frmFileSystem = lainf.inflate(R.layout.dlg_filesystem, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lilaFileSystem));

    dlg_filesystem = new DlgFileSystem(this);
    dlg_filesystem.setView(frmFileSystem);
    dlg_filesystem.setCancelable(true);
    dlg_filesystem.setButton( 'aceptar' , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which )
    {
        alert( dlg_filesystem.prueba );
    }});
    dlg_filesystem.setButton2( 'cancelar' , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which )
    {
    }});
    dlg_filesystem.show();
}

}
```

and

```
public class DlgFileSystem extends AlertDialog{
public String prueba;
private Context context;
private View frmFileSystem;

public DlgFileSystem(Context context)
{ 
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void setView( View frmFileSystem )
{
    super.setView(frmFileSystem);
    this.frmFileSystem = frmFileSystem;
    TextView txprueba = (TextView)frmFileSystem.findViewById(R.id.txPrueba);
    txprueba.setText("adios");
}   
}
```